# How to get the http response as a list of int?

Tags: dart, https

I do a request to fetch a 24-byte binary file (in the example below, I change the URI to apple.com).

And I need to get the response as a list of bytes.
So how can I get the body as a `List<int>`?

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


void main() async {
  
  
 try {
  final r = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://apple.com')
    , headers: {
      "Cache-control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
    }
  );
  
  
  
  if (r.statusCode!=200) {
    
    print("Error ${r.statusCode}");
    
  }
   

  print("OK: reponse headers: ${r.headers}");   
   
  r.headers.entries.map((e)=>print("${e.key}: ${e.value}"));
  
   print("OK: reponse is: ${r.body}");
  
 }catch(e) {
   print("Error: $e");
 }
}
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response/bodyBytes.html